# Editing caption panel

Tags: google-apps-script

**Dont know why return unexpected error ocurred:**

*I am trying to edit a caption panel but if i make "return app", error appears.
My function panel Admin creates my Captionpanel and my function createActivatePanelAdmin gets the caption panel and try to edit the content becouse if one itembar is selected the content of Caption Panel must change.*

```
function panelAdmin(){

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LOGS_SHEET_ID);
  var verticalPanelAdmin = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("verticalPanelAdmin");
  var mainPanelIndex = app.createCaptionPanel().setText("Index");

  var menuBar = app.createMenuBar().setId("menuBar").setAnimationEnabled(true);//For vertical menubar(true)

  var hdPanelAdminIndex = app.createServerHandler("createPanelAdminIndex").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);
  var hdPanelCreateUserPanel = app.createServerHandler("createUserPanelAdmin").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);
  var hdPanelActive = app.createServerHandler("createActivatePanelAdmin").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);
  var hdPanelDeleteUserPanel = app.createServerHandler("deleteUserPanel").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);
  var hdPanelSearchUserPanel = app.createServerHandler("searchUserPanel").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);
  var hdPanelExitUserPanel = app.createServerHandler("ExitUserPanel").addCallbackElement(mainPanelIndex);

  var menuItem0 = app.createMenuItem('Inicio ', hdPanelAdminIndex);
  var menuItem1 = app.createMenuItem('Crear Usuarios', hdPanelCreateUserPanel);
  var menuItem2 = app.createMenuItem('Activar Usuarios', hdPanelActive);
  var menuItem3 = app.createMenuItem('Borrar Usuarios', hdPanelDeleteUserPanel);
  var menuItem4 = app.createMenuItem('Buscar', hdPanelSearchUserPanel);
  var menuItem5 = app.createMenuItem('Salir', hdPanelExitUserPanel);
  //top level menu items


  //create menuItem separators
  var separator0 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
  var separator1 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
  var separator2 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
  var separator3 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
  var separator4 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();
  var separator5 = app.createMenuItemSeparator();

  //Add the menu item separators and menuItem to the MenuBar
  menuBar.addSeparator(separator0).addItem(menuItem0).addSeparator(separator1)
    .addItem(menuItem1).addSeparator(separator2)
    .addItem(menuItem2).addSeparator(separator3)
    .addItem(menuItem3).addSeparator(separator4)
    .addItem(menuItem4).addSeparator(separator5)
    .addItem(menuItem5).addSeparator(separator0);
  verticalPanelAdmin.add(menuBar);
  verticalPanelAdmin.add(mainPanelIndex);
  app.add(verticalPanelAdmin);

  return app;

};
```

---

```
  function createActivatePanelAdmin(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(LOGS_SHEET_ID);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var verticalPanelAdmin = app.getElementById("verticalPanelAdmin");

  var menuBar = app.getElementById("menuBar");
  var mainPanelIndex = app.getElementById("mainPanelIndex");
      mainPanelIndex.setText("Sistema de creación de usuarios");

  var mainPanelActivateAdmin = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("mainPanelActivateAdmin");


      /*FROM HERE WORKS CORRECTLY (TESTED)*/

  var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var rowsToConfirm = confirmReg();
  var lastRow = numRows(rowsToConfirm);


  if (rowsToConfirm != null){
    var flexTableRegAdmin = app.createFlexTable().setId("flexTableRegAdmin").setBorderWidth(1);
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 0, "ID");
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 1, "NOMBRE");
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 2, "PASS");
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 3, "EMAIL");
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 4, "ESTADO");
    flexTableRegAdmin.setText(0, 5, "ACTIVAR");

    var check = new Array(lastRow);

    for(var r = 0; r < lastRow; r++){
      for(var c = 0; c < lastCol; c++){
        var text = rowsToConfirm[r][c].toString();

        flexTableRegAdmin.setText(r+1, c, text);


      }
      var id = rowsToConfirm[r][0];
      check[r] = app.createCheckBox().setName("chk_"+id).setId("chk_"+id);
      flexTableRegAdmin.setWidget(r+1, lastCol, check[r]);
    }//end fors
  }//end if

  var botMod = app.createButton().setText("Activar").setId("botStatus");
  var botHandle = app.createServerHandler("changeStatus").addCallbackElement(mainPanelActivateAdmin);
  botMod.addClickHandler(botHandle);

  /*TO HERE*/


  mainPanelActivateAdmin.add(flexTableRegAdmin);
  mainPanelActivateAdmin.add(botMod);

  mainPanelIndex.add(mainPanelActivateAdmin);
  return app;
  };
```

**Thanks for help! AND I have to say that the flextable is ok, i builded it in other site so don't spend your time trying to see if the error is in Flextable or botton_send **

THE PROBLEM IS IN PANELS (I tried to clear code)

[image: Thats is]

EDIT:  (I am only trying to remove the captionPanel and i can't. Unexpected error)

```
function createActivatePanelAdmin(){

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var verticalPanelAdmin = app.getElementById("verticalPanelAdmin");
  var mainPanelIndex = app.getElementById("mainPanelIndex");
  verticalPanelAdmin.remove(mainPanelIndex);
  return app;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Waqar, your code is not testable since it calls variables defined outside of it.

These errors occurs often when you try to get by ID something with the wrong ID (ie an id that doesn't exist), so I'd recommend you dubble check every ID of every panel and widgets you use, there might be a typo somewhere...

EDIT : there is one error I think I (maybe) found :

in the first part of the code you wrote :

```
  var verticalPanelAdmin = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("verticalPanelAdminIndex");
```

and in the second function you call this panel with :

```
  var verticalPanelAdmin = app.getElementById("verticalPanelAdmin");
```

The ID's are different... is that normal ?

**EDIT 2** : also a problem here ... First function :

```
 var mainPanelIndex = app.createCaptionPanel().setText("Index");// no ID is defined
```

and then you call it with

```
  var mainPanelIndex = app.getElementById("mainPanelIndex");
```

try it and keep checking yourself also please...

Comment: not it was a mistake, i changed it but error persist. I am going to copy the full code without variables defined outside of it.

Comment: I edited it, now you shouldn't have problems to help me. I cant find the good way

Comment: I saw your own answer... I'm not sure I understood what you mean but the error you had was most probably caused by the missing ID (see edit2) I see no bug in this behavior ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say where the problem exactly is. You may debug your application by commenting part of the code so that you can narrow the area where the problem resides. I come across such errors many times and follow this approach. Hope this will help you too.

Happy Apps Scripting

Answer (score 0):

**THE PROBLEM WAS:**

---

1 - YOU CANT EDIT A PANEL (created and showed)

2 - MUST CREATE A NEW PANEL PER OPTION MENU.

---

**SOLUTION:**

---

1 - MAKE CLEAR APPLICATION (in my case I prefer CLEAR THE ABSOLUTE PANEL: which i added before all).

2 - CREATE A NEW VERTICAL PANEL ("V")

3 - CREATE A NEW ABSOLUTE PANEL ("A")

4 - GET MENUBAR BY ID (THIS IS POSSIBLE BECAUSE YOU ARE NOT GOING TO CHANGE IT)

5 - CREATING A NEW CAPTION PANEL ("captionActivePanel").

```
    UiApp.getActiveApplication app = var ();
    app.getElementById absolutePanel = var ("absolutePanel");
    app.remove (absolutePanel);
    var a = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId("a");
    var v = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("v");
    var menuBar = app.getElementById("menuBar");
    var captionActivePanel = app.createCaptionPanel().setId(captionActivePanel).setText("Bienvenido al sistema de activación de usuarios");
```

Once we have the panel you want to introduce (in this case "flexTableRegAdmin" and a simple button for ex.) introduce it inside CAPTION PANEL

```
    v.add (flexTableRegAdmin);
    v.add (botMod);
    captionActivePanel.add (v)

    a.add (menuBar);
    a.add (captionActivePanel);
    app.add (a);
```

***Waqar Ahmad thank you for making me see that it is necessary to comment to make things works!! I think i could report that bug becouse it's necesary edit the content of panels***